# Interpret Numeric values as String in excel

Tags: excel, csv, formatting

I have a CSV file. This file contains large numeric sequences which excel automatically interprets as numeric and displays them in Exponential form. What modification should be done in my csv file, so that excel treats these values as text.

Example:

```
ABC,1000000000000000,HOME,PAIR
```

Appears as

```
ABC,1E+15,HOME,PAIR
```

How to make it look as it is in excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your csv file as it is.

- On the Data menu, click Text to Columns.
- In step 3, mark the second
  column and define the data Format as Text.

[image: screenshot (German Version)]

More Info on [MS support website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214261)

Comment: Actually I can do that. But since I am going to send the file to another person who just double clicks on the file and expects to see those numbers as text, its not up to me. I need another way around, so that I modify the csv plain file in such a way that excel treats numbers as text.